# Database able to resampling a time series of events + duration into concurrent events

Tags: database, time-series, influxdb

I've been googling for this for a while and haven't found a proper solution. I have a time series that has the following structure:

```
Time              Alarm  AlarmDuration
01.08.2015 00:01  7       5   seconds
01.08.2015 00:04  12      3   seconds
01.08.2015 00:05  8      `12  seconds
01.08.2015 00:08  1       1   seconds
01.08.2015 00:10  6       10  seconds
...
```

I would want to know what are the alarms at a certain moment. Further I would like to query other series in the time range of a certain alarm.

For this I would have to transform this data into something like this:

```
Time              Alarms
01.08.2015 00:01  7          
01.08.2015 00:04  7,12      
01.08.2015 00:05  7,12,8      
01.08.2015 00:06  12,8      
01.08.2015 00:07  8 
01.08.2015 00:08  8,1 
01.08.2015 00:09  8 
01.08.2015 00:10  8,6 
01.08.2015 00:11  8,6 
...
```

Any advice about handling this kind of data with **influxdb** (our primary choice)? Is there any open source database designed for this kind of time series?

Comment: Why do you want a comma separated value?  That's a SQL antipattern. How will this eventually be used?  Perhaps we can suggest a better alternative? *(Such was one row per alarm per second?)*

Comment: Mat, thanks for your prompt reply. I do not look for comma separated value at all!  I used this solution just to synthesize the problem and give a data structure example.  Any advice is welcome! However any solution is also welcome.. SQL or NOSQL.

Comment: Usage examples.. Query all the users active while alarm 7 and 12.  However, one row per alarm per second seems to be up to now the most feasible recipe despite is an huge amount of data! Hundreds of alarms, years of data each istance.. isn't t?

Comment: Create a calendar table.  *(One with all the dates you'll ever need, for this and every other need.  Search SO or the Web for usage of Calendar Tables.)*  Then you just need to left join your alarm records to the calendar.  You'll get NULLs where there are no alarms, and multiple records for dates with multiple alarms.

Comment: Why not store the alerts in a time-series database and then running a select query such as SELECT period, count(alarm), sum(alarmduration) FROM ... group by period(1 minute)